# Different asm on Windows x64 from a CS:APP x86-64 Linux example function for swapping a long

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention, win64

i am reading CS:APP 3rd edition (Ch3. pic 3.7 GAS assembly code)

```
long exchange(long* xp, long y)
{
  long x = *xp;
  *xp = y;
  return x;
}

exchange:
    movq  (%rdi), %rax
    movq  %rsi, (%rdi)
    ret
```

i wonder why below assembly code(1. asm : which is converted to nasm) does not work?

i had diassembled working c function to nasm assembly source code using c2nasm. it is quite different to original assembly.

main.cpp :

```
int main()
{
  long a = 4;
  // long b = exchange(&a, 3);
  long b = exchange2(&a, 3);

  printf("[a: %ld] [b: %ld]\n", a, b);

  return 0;
}
```

1.asm :

```
BITS 64

; default rel
default abs 

global    exchange2 
section   .text

exchange2:
    ;;; this code does not works
    ;;; program output    ->        [a: 4] [b: 0]
    mov rax, [rdi]
    mov [rdi], rsi 
    ret

    ;;; this code works, generated by c2nasm.
    ;;; program output    ->        [a: 3] [b: 4]
    ; push    rbp
    ; mov     rbp, rsp
    ; sub     rsp, 16
    ; mov     qword [rbp+10H], rcx
    ; mov     dword [rbp+18H], edx
    ; mov     rax, qword [rbp+10H]
    ; mov     eax, dword [rax]
    ; mov     dword [rbp-4H], eax
    ; mov     rax, qword [rbp+10H]
    ; mov     edx, dword [rbp+18H]
    ; mov     dword [rax], edx
    ; mov     eax, dword [rbp-4H]
    ; leave
    ; ret
```

---

EDIT: thanks!
working version for Windows x64 `long long exchange(long long*, long long)`:

```
BITS 64

default rel

global    _exchange2     ; Windows name-mangling prepends _ to C names
section   .text

_exchange2:
    mov rax, [rcx]
    mov [rcx], rdx 
    ret
```

Comment: Windows uses a different calling convention than x86-64 System V ABI (used on BSD and Linux).Your version of exchange2 doesn't work because it is not compatible with [Windows.64-bit calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention). In that convention the first 4 integer class parameters are passed through RCX, RDX, R8, R9. Try `mov eax, [rcx]`
    `mov [rcx], edx` 
    `ret` .On win64 longs are 32-bit so you can use the 32-bit registers instead of RAX and RDX

Comment: Your "working" version does a 64-bit copy, so it's only correct for `long long`, not `long`.  Your current version writes 4 extra bytes outside the `long` destination.  Also, there's no reason to use `default abs`, but it has no effect anyway because you aren't using any `[symbol]` addressing modes.

Comment: `default rel` is preferred, I'd recommend always using that.  IDK why you commented it out and used `default abs` (which is the default anyway).  If `c2nasm` includes that by default, then it's just reminding you that you probably want to change the NASM default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is for the x86-64 System V ABI, used on Linux, OS X, and other non-Windows platforms (64-bit `long`, args in RDI, RSI, ...)

You compiled for Windows x64, which uses a different calling convention (args in RCX, RDX), and `long` is a 32-bit type.

---

Also you compiled with optimization disabled so the asm is full of store/reload noise.  With optimization it would be basically the same but with different registers.

BTW, you can use `gcc -O3 -masm=intel` to get Intel-syntax assembly which is a lot closer to NASM syntax.  (It's *not* NASM syntax though; it's MASM-like for addressing modes, and still uses GAS directives.)