# Difference between amd64 and Intel x86-64 stack frame

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, function-call

I'm learn ATT asm, so I'm also reading Linux amd64 ABI, and I notice *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective* (CSAPP) has the same content (stack frame layout). I found the stack frame layout is different, their return address is divided into difference places. CSAPP asm code seems to set up on Intel x86_x64 (is this IA-64?).

Below is amd64 stack frame layout, [3.2.1 Registers and the Stack Frame](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf)
[image: amd64 stack frame layout]

Below is CSAPP stack frame layout.
[image: csapp stack frame layout]

I assume Intel x86_x64 is IA-64, so I check [Linux core IA-64 ABI](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/IA64conventions.pdf), and found below picture.
[image]

And, I found the CSAPP describes *data transfer*.

> When a function has more than six integral arguments, the other ones are passed on the stack. Assume that procedure P calls procedure Q with n integral arguments, such that n > 6. Then the code for P must allocate a stack frame with enough storage for arguments 7 through n.

No way to correspond, I don't quite understand why there are difference. maybe I found wrong documentation.

**Update:**
I know that amd64 is not IA-64, also know IA-64 is Intel's Itanium. I read a little bit of wiki before asking question. I think CSAPP is in Linux environment, so I should read Linux ABI, but official documentation provides architecture list doesn't contain Intel x86_64, So appear I assume Intel x86_x64 is IA-64. Sorry, I am a novice. I want to know stack frame layout of CSAPP from which architecture, I think I will work in Unix-like, so I should learn which architecture.

[image]

Comment: IA-64 is not x86_64 or amd64. IA-64 stands for Itanium Architecture, where Itanium was/is a VLIW architecture with 128/256-bit instruction packs, 64-bit registers/bus  and software directed instruction scheduling. Parameter passing happens with a sliding register window.

Comment: To add to what Aki Suihkonen said: amd64 is also known as x86_64, x64, Intel 64, EM-64T or IA-32e.  But not IA-64.

Comment: I assume "csapp" refers to the book *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective*?  You should spell that out, as I don't think many people will know what it means.

Answer (score 3):

> No way to correspond, I don't quite understand why there are difference. maybe I found wrong documentation. :-)

There are up to 5 different calling conventions here:

- The System V AMD64 ABI, which includes a red zone.
- The Linux kernel ABI for x86_64; which is System V AMD64 ABI but without any red zone.
- Microsoft x64 calling convention; which has "shadow space" (and no red zone)
- Whatever Linux uses on Itanium (which has nothing to do with x86_64).
- None of the above. For pure assembly you don't have to conform to any ABI (until/unless you're calling a shared library or something written in another language).

The "csapp stack frame layout" has no red zone; so it must be one of the other possibilities. I'd assume the Microsoft x64 calling convention is the most likely (where the diagram's "saved registers" are the 32 bytes of "shadow space"); as a user-space application is more likely than kernel-space code, 80x86 is more likely than Itanium, and it doesn't make sense to have a diagram for "no calling convention, each function does what it likes".

Comment: IIRC, the CS:APP textbook uses examples with GCC compiling for x86-64 Linux, so AMD64 System V.  As in [Different asm on Windows x64 from a CS:APP x86-64 Linux example function for swapping a long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55274794).  I don't know whether they disable the red-zone or not, but it doesn't usually come up because they enable optimization so only non-leaf functions need any extra stack space.    (Of course the *global edition* of CS:APP replaced the practice problems with nonsense written by incompetents hired by the publishers, but it's still supposedly Linux GCC.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Isn't that weird? csapp should be `AMD64`, but it is not following the ABI rules.

Comment: @OnlyWick: What are you talking about?  The CS:APP image you show in your question matches AMD64 System V, assuming all the args are integer/pointer or otherwise small enough to fit in one integer reg (thus the 7th arg being the first stack arg).  Using the red-zone is fully optional, if that's what you mean.  The ABI doesn't *require* you to store/reload anything below RSP.

Comment: @PeterCordes  I think I will work in `Unix-like`, so I should learn AMD64 ABI?

Comment: If it were Windows x64 then the arguments on the stack would have to start with argument 5, not 7.  I agree that it is SysV ABI and the red zone is simply not shown in the diagram.

Comment: @NateEldredge you're right, I saw [x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170). stack frame layout of CS:APP is not the Microsoft x64.

Comment: @NateEldredge So `return address` belongs to `caller` or `callee` ?

Comment: @OnlyWick: There's no guarantee that the caller will find the return address in its red-zone after the callee returns, so technically the callee could load it into a register and then overwrite it in memory.  And then return with `jmp *%rcx` or whatever, as long as it returns to the return address with `%rsp` the same place as it was before the call.  Or copy it further down the stack and then return with `ret 16` or something.  But nobody does that in practice because it would be highly inefficient, especially `pop` / `jmp` which would mismatch the return-address predictor for future rets.

Comment: @PeterCordes I got it, Thanks! That's what I want!  :-)